# Classicthesis color not showing

Tags: color, classicthesis

In the classicthesis package, when I change the color from Maroon to ForestGreen, I get the following error: package xcolor Error: Undefined color 'ForestGreen' and the text is black. I would like the text to be ForestGreen.

This is part of the code I'm using.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{xcolor} % [dvipsnames]
\definecolor{CTcitation}{named}{ForestGreen}
\definecolor{CTurl}{named}{ForestGreen} 
\definecolor{CTtitle}{named}{ForestGreen} 
\definecolor{CTlink}{named}{ForestGreen}
```

Comment: Please provide a MWE, Minimal Working Example. As it is, your code isn't compilable for testing, and there's a lot to add to make it compilable.

Comment: @Miyase There's a bunch of different files that contain the code, how should I post them? Not exactly sure which is relevant either.

Comment: Note the *Minimal* part of MWE. You should just trim your code to a single file, as short as possible, containing just enough code (and packages) to trigger the problem. Remember that people helping here do it on their own time, so the idea is to simplify it as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is just a suggestion, but try to use

```
\definecolor{forestgreen}{rgb}{0.13, 0.55, 0.13}
```

from here http://latexcolor.com/

[image]

Comment: That seemed to work.